# Getting timestamp of event from file name in logstash

Tags: ruby, logging, logstash

We have a process that writes events to a file, without a timestamp.  The file names themselves are suffixed with a timestamp, which is the timestamp that should be used for all the events in the file.  Now, I am trying to parse the file by using the input file plugin of logstash.  Is there a way by which I could get the name of the file to a field, so that I can then use the gsub filter to extract out the timestamp and then use the date filter to set the timestamp to the event?

Comment: Would you like to share an example of the filename, and show a sample of the code you use to open the file?

Comment: an example filename is stats.log.1317452400.  I have not written any code to open the file.  I use logstash's input file plugin to do that:  http://logstash.net/docs/1.1.1/inputs/file

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar need, and asked this question again - so you can find a more up-to-date answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22916200/logstash-how-to-add-file-name-as-a-field) thanks to Jettro Coenradie :)