# Logstash grok custom pattern yields no fields

Tags: logstash

Newbie alert!

I have the following grok filter:

```
filter {

        grok {
                match   =>  [ "message","%{DATESTAMP:timestamp}" ]
                match   =>  [ "message", "(?<number_after_timestamp>[0-9]{8}\s\w+)"]
                match   =>  [ "message", "(?<error_or_debug>(ERROR|DEBUG))"]
                match   =>  [ "message", "(?<first_part>ORB\.thread\.pool.*(?=\s{2}))" ]
                match   =>  [ "message", "(?<exception_class_name>(?<=\<Exception class name\=\s).*?\>)" ]
                match   =>  [ "message", "(?<exception_message>(?<=\<Exception message\=).*?(?=\>))" ]

        }   


}
```

Individually every one of those patterns matched exactly the chunk of text I need when tested using the grok debugger. In the grok debugger the named pattern name is used as the field and emitted just fine. However when I run this over the same log events I used in the grok debugger none of the data from the log event lines or the field names is emitted.

For example the exception class name pattern yields:

```
{
    "exception_class_name": [
    [
      "com.ultatica.bd.exceptions.TTFException>"
    ]
   ]
}
```

But when run against the data from logstash command line -> not a sausage!

Would really appreciate any help.

Thanks

The logfile is like this:

```
[30/09/14 23:07:15:195 BST] 00000043 SystemOut O ERROR 32109 Tue Sep 30 23:07:15 BST 2014 ORB.thread.pool : 2 webuser com.ultra.bd.services.UltraticoCustomerService.processRequest API getPerson  <Exception class name= com.Ultratico.bd.exceptions.UCOException> <Exception message= e05CX432182S> <UCOException Error = 32109>

[30/09/14 23:07:15:200 BST] 00000043 SystemOut O ERROR 32109 Tue Sep 30 23:07:15 BST 2014 ORB.thread.pool : 2 webuser com.Ultratico.ecrm.framework.sessionHandler.UltraticoSessionHandler.execute  <Exception class name= com.Ultratico.bd.exceptions.UCOException> <Exception message= e05CX432182S> <UCOException Error = 32109>
```

Comment: Can you add a few lines from the input (log file etc)?

Comment: OP edited to show sample log lines

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use grok to add the log filename as a field in logstash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23780000/use-grok-to-add-the-log-filename-as-a-field-in-logstash)

Comment: I found the gro debugger incredibly useful in these situations where I could not determine why my grok filter was not working:

http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the input, the way I would try to parse it is using a single match expression. In logstash I use multiple match patterns as a way of parsing different types of log entries. e.g.

1. match pattern 1 => NO
2. match pattern 2 => YES
3. match pattern 3 => NO

So for your example I would do something like:

```
filter {
    grok {      
        break_on_match => false
        match => [ "message", "%{SYSLOG5424SD:timestamp} %{NUMBER:number_after_timestamp} (?<forget1>.*) (?<error_or_debug>ERROR|DEBUG) %{NUMBER:process_id} (?<timestamp_2>.{7} \d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} \w{3} \d{4}) %{JAVACLASS:origin} : (?<first_part>.*) %{JAVACLASS:exception_class_name} (?<exception_message>.*)" ]
        match => [ "message", "..some other pattern you want to extract.." ]
        match => [ "message", "..some other pattern you want to extract.." ]            
    }
}
```

Could be tidied up but you get the gist..

Comment: Thanks Andrew. That makes sense to me. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax for [grok](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/grok) is `match => [ "field", "pattern1", "pattern2", "pattern3",...,"patternN"]`.  Multiple `match` arguments won't work because it loads them into a hash -- causing it to only use the last one.

You would need to create multiple `grok` blocks each with `break_on_match => false` to do it the way you are showing, but it would be better if you used the first form and did full patterns to match whole lines so that you can avoid the inevitable `_grokparsefailure`s.

Comment: Yes. that was it. Thank you. When I split the Grok statements out I now see all the fields. Thanks so much. I will look into your suggestion. Appreciate it. Logstash feels tough to work on....