# How to send path information in logstash forwarder

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-forwarder

My Logstash forwarder is running on some different host from the logstash server. Now I want to send the exact path information of the file from where the logstashforwarder read the log. Is there some way by which we can do this.. Below is my logstash-forwarder conig file

```
    {
  "network": {
    "servers": [ "10.93.69.55:5002"],
    "timeout": 15,
    "ssl ca": "/home/lambda/gitprojects/logstash-forwarder/logstash-forwarder.crt"
  },
  "files": [
    {
      "paths": [
        "/home/lambda/deployments/dashboard/src/log/*.log"
       ],
      "fields": { "type": "dashboard" }
    }
   ]
}
```

As shown above i have used *.log to include al the error log files (error.log, process.log, etc) . Now i want to send the file name along with the log to logstash server.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22916200/logstash-how-to-add-file-name-as-a-field

Answer (score 0):

Define multiple file inputs and add a new field depending on the file's path. Pseudo config:

```
input {
    file {
        type => "serverlog"
        path => [ "/log/error*.log" ]
        add_field => { "file_source" => "error" }
    }
    file {
        type => "serverlog"
        path => [ "/log/process*.log" ]
        add_field => { "file_source" => "process" }
    }
}
```