# Create a new index in elasticsearch for each log file by date

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

**Currently**
I have completed the above task by using one log file and passes data with logstash to one index in elasticsearch :

`yellow open   logstash-2016.10.19   5   1    1000807            0    364.8mb        364.8mb`

**What I actually want to do**

If i have the following logs files which are named according to Year,Month and Date

```
MyLog-2016-10-16.log
MyLog-2016-10-17.log
MyLog-2016-10-18.log
MyLog-2016-11-05.log
MyLog-2016-11-02.log
MyLog-2016-11-03.log
```

I would like to tell logstash to read by Year,Month and Date and create the following indexes :

`yellow open   MyLog-2016-10-16.log`
`yellow open   MyLog-2016-10-17.log`
`yellow open   MyLog-2016-10-18.log`
`yellow open   MyLog-2016-11-05.log`
`yellow open   MyLog-2016-11-02.log`
`yellow open   MyLog-2016-11-03.log`

Please could I have some guidance  as to how do i need to go about doing this ?

Thanks You

Comment: How are you reading the files?

Comment: If you are using the file input, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22916200/logstash-how-to-add-file-name-as-a-field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is also simple as that :

```
 output {
   elasticsearch {
      hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
      index => "MyLog-%{+YYYY-MM-DD}.log"
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the lines in the file contain datetime info, you should be using the date{} filter to set @timestamp from that value.  If you do this, you can use the output format that @Renaud provided, "MyLog-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}".

If the lines don't contain the datetime info, you can use the input's path for your index name, e.g. "%{path}".  To get just the basename of the path:

```
mutate {
    gsub => [ "path", ".*/", "" ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

wont this configuration in output section be sufficient for your purpose ??

```
output {
    elasticsearch {
        embedded => false
        host => localhost
        port => 9200
        protocol => http
        cluster => 'elasticsearch'
        index => "syslog-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }
}
```