# Logstash: Dynamic field names based on filename

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I got a filename in the format `<key>:<value>-<key>:<value>.log` like e.g. `pr:64-author:mxinden-platform:aws.log` containing logs of a test run.

I want to stream each line of the file to elasticsearch via logstash. Each line should be treated as a separate document. Each document should get the fields according to the filename. So e.g. for the above example let's say log-line `17-12-07 foo something happened bar` would get the fields: `pr` with value `64`, `author` with value `mxinden` and `platform` with value `aws`.

At the point in time, where I write the logstash configuration **I do not know the names of the fields**.

How do I dynamically add fields to each line based on the fields contained in the filename?

The **static** approach so far is:

```
filter {
  mutate { add_field => { "file" => "%{[@metadata][s3][key]}"} }
  else {
    grok { match => { "file" => "pr:%{NUMBER:pr}-" } }
    grok { match => { "file" => "author:%{USERNAME:author}-" } } 
    grok { match => { "file" => "platform:%{USERNAME:platform}-" } }
  }
}
```

Changes to the filename structure are fine.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if I understand your question, but can't you just match your filepath as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22916200/logstash-how-to-add-file-name-as-a-field?rq=1). Something like `filter {
  grok {
    match => ["path","%{GREEDYDATA}%{WORD}:%{NUMBER:pr}-%{WORD}:%{WORD:author}-%{WORD}:%{WORD:platform}.log"]
  }
}` could work for you...

Comment: @Phonolog But that would imply, that I know, which keys are in the filename. I don't know the keys like e.g. `author`, `platform`, `pr`, ..., at that point in time. I would like to determine the keys dynamically.

My use case is, that I want to be able to add new fields to the filename without touching the Logstash configuration.

Comment: The way I would do it is to get the whole filename into a field (excluding the .log) then use the kv filter to split on that field with the field split = "-" and value split = ":"

Comment: @mxinden Alright I got it now... Dan's solution sounds like a good way to go then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question based on @dan-griffiths [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47696923/logstash-dynamic-field-names-based-on-filename?noredirect=1#comment82407458_47696923):

Solution for a file like `pr=64,author=mxinden,platform=aws.log` is to use the Elasticsearch [**kv** filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-kv.html) like e.g.:

```
  filter {
    kv {
      source => "file"
      field_split => ","
    }
  }
```

where `file` is a field extracted from the filename via the AWS S3 input plugin.