# Insert JSON file into Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, etl, filebeat, kibana-6

I have a python script that creates a JSON file every now and then (no specific schedule) I want to store this JSON file in elasticsearch when it is created. What is the best tool in elastic-stack to handle this? Is it can be done with Logstash or Beats? Also I have another script that creates a custom file .klm every now and then (again no specific schedule) I want to insert the file's name as soon as it is created so again is this can be done with Logstash or Beats, or any other suggestion of where I can start?!

I am using Elastic stack version 6.0.2

Answer (score 0):

You need to 
**[Index](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.index)**  the Json document using the Python client

I recommend reading the ES docs too, so you understand how ES handles indices and aliases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use logstash with the [file input](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html) to read the files and the [elasticsearch output](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html) to write the content of the file to elasticsearch. For the .klm file, the file input in logstash adds a `path` field containing the path of the file, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22916484/6113627) on how to retrieve the file name from the path.

If you've never used logstash, start [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/getting-started-with-logstash.html).

I can't comment on if it's possible to do with beats.